# Validate is showing warning messages at same time as isset message

Tags: codeigniter

I have this code here which should validate member login information

For some reason `$this->error['warning']` keeps on showing up at the same time even if the input post username or password is not set.

> Question How to make sure my if the password and username is not set to not run second check untill both are completed.

[image]

```
public function validate() {

    /* First Checks */
    if (!$this->input->post('username')) {
        $this->error['username'] = 'You have missed the username input!';
    }

    if (!$this->input->post('password')) {
        $this->error['password'] = 'You have missed password input!';
    }

    /* Second Checks */
    if (($this->input->post('password') != '') && ($this->input->post('username') != '')) {

        if (!$this->member->login($this->input->post('password'), $this->input->post('username'))) {
            $this->error['warning'] = 'In correct username or password!';
        } 

        if (!$this->member->approved($this->input->post('username'))) {
            $this->error['warning'] = 'Your account not approved yet!';
        }

    }

    return !$this->error;
}
```

Full Controller

```
<?php

class Login extends CI_Controller {

    private $error = array();

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {

        $this->data['title'] = 'Members Login';

        if ($this->member->getmemberid()) {
            redirect(base_url('admin/members/dashboard'));
        }

        if (($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST') && $this->validate()) {

            redirect(base_url('admin/members/dashboard'));
        }

        if (isset($this->error['warning'])) {
            $this->data['error_warning'] = $this->error['warning'];
        } else {
            $this->data['error_warning'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->error['username'])) {
            $this->data['error_username'] = $this->error['username'];
        } else {
            $this->data['error_username'] = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->error['password'])) {
            $this->data['error_password'] = $this->error['password'];
        } else {
            $this->data['error_password'] = '';
        }

        if ($this->input->post('username')) {
            $this->data['username'] = $this->input->post('username');
        } else {
            $this->data['username'] = '';
        }

        if ($this->input->post('password')) {
            $this->data['password'] = $this->input->post('password');
        } else {
            $this->data['password'] = '';
        }


        $this->load->view('admin/template/common/header', $this->data);
        $this->load->view('admin/template/member/login', $this->data);
        $this->load->view('admin/template/common/footer');
    }

    public function validate() {
        if (!$this->input->post('username')) {
            $this->error['username'] = 'You have missed the username input!';
        }

        if (!$this->input->post('password')) {
            $this->error['password'] = 'You have missed password input!';
        }

        if (($this->input->post('password') != '') && ($this->input->post('username') != '')) {

            if (!$this->member->login($this->input->post('password'), $this->input->post('username'))) {
                $this->error['warning'] = 'In correct username or password!';
            } 

            if (!$this->member->approved($this->input->post('username'))) {
                $this->error['warning'] = 'Your account not approved yet!';
            }

        }

        return !$this->error;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## solution

It was a simple error caused buy not putting

```
public $data = array();
```

At the top above construct now working so far